# Expression body in method constructor

Tags: c#

This is most likely not what it's called - I simply have no idea what it is called...

So lately, the project I'm working on has got me thinking (I've also seen this somewhere before) how to achieve the following design..

It seems like an expression body but for the life of me I can not get it to work one way or another.

Basically what I want to achieve is to write the following (on razor should that make any difference):

```
@(
    AIHelper.CreateQuickForm<LoginModel>(formId: "myCustomId", formMethod: FormMethod.Post)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "another damn class" })
     .ShowSubmit()
     .On(x => { x.OnSubmit("onFormSubmit"); e.OnCancel("onFormCancel"); })
)
```

Now - my question is how to achieve the `.On` part.

`.On(x => { x.OnSubmit("onFormSubmit"); e.OnCancel("onFormCancel"); })`

I've tried using:

```
public QuickFormEvents On(Func<QuickFormEvents> expr)
{
    return _Events;
}
```

Which is nowhere what I'm looking for.

I do have a class defined that should be 'injected' (can we even call it that?) into the expression body called `QuickFormEvents`.

Any pointers in the right direction would be apprecited.

Comment: It's an `Action<Something>`, not a `Func` -- it takes a parameter, but returns nothing.

Comment: @canton7 Beauty, not sure how I missed that one.. go pop it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `On` method should take an `Action<Something>`, not a `Func`. It takes a parameter, but doesn't return anything.

You probably want something like:

```
public Something On(Action<SomethingElse> action)
{
    // store or invoke 'action', passing something as appropriate
    return this; // return this to allow chaining
}
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed the point of `Action`. Will accept as correct answer in 7 minutes.